# getting infinte amount of inputs from the user than printing the biggest 3 , without using arrays

Tags: c++, sum, infinite-loop

First time around, first time learning to code anything. Sorry for my ignorance.
So I've been asked to code a program that gets infinite amount of number from the users until he submits the number I manage to do so very well, but I also need to print the biggest sum of a following three inputs, for example, the user inputs `4,20,2,4,11,9,8,1` the program should print `11,9,8` because the sum of those 3 is greater than all other 3.
I must tell you I cannot use arrays, I know its a bummber but I know it is possible to do so without.

I was trying to build a function that tries to act like an array but I can't really call her back since its a two-variable function and one of them is the input, which I obviously don't know. was working on this question for 5 hours now and thought ill ask for your wisdom

```cpp
cout << " enter numbers as long as you wish" << endl;
cout << "when you wish to stop enter the number 1" << endl;
int n;
int sum;
int i = 1;


while (n != 1) { 

    cin >> n;
    remember(i, n);
    if (n == 1) {
        cout << "you choosed to stop " << endl;
        break;
    }
    i++;
}
```

And the function I was trying to build is really simple but I can't call any specific value for example `remember(1, n)` when I want to sum them up and see who is bigger.

```cpp
int remember(int i, int n){
    return n;
}
```

*** Please note that the sums that are being tested are the sums of the numbers in the exact order that the user-submitted therefor 11,9,8 is the output and NOT 20,11,9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need seven variables: Three which is the "window" you're currently reading, and which you check your sum with; Three which is the "biggest sum" triple; And one which is the current input.

For each input you read into the "current input" variable, you *shift* the window down one value and set the top variable to the just read input.

Then you take the sum of all three values in the window, and check if it's bigger than the sum of the current "biggest sum" triple. If it is, then you make the "biggest sum" triple equal to the current window values.

Iterate until there is no more input, and then print the "biggest" values.

---

Regarding the *shifting* of the three window values, lets say you have three variables named `window1`, `window2` and `window3` then you could shift like this:

```
window1 = window2;
window2 = window3;
window3 = current;
```

Checking the sum is as easy as

```
if ((window1 + window2 + window3) > (biggest1 + biggest2 + biggest3))
```

All window and biggest variables need to be initialized to the lowest possibly value for the type (for `int` that would be [`std::numeric_limits<int>::min()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/min)).

Since you initialize all values, there's no need to have special cases for the first and second input.

Iterating while there's input could be done by doing

```
while (std::cin >> current)
```

Comment: that's amazing but i cant seem to understand how to get infinite amount of inputs which i think means loop your answer

Comment: @YarinShani "Iterate until there is no more input" Added example as well

Comment: this solution is just amazing but why b1 b2 and b3 is allways 0 for me, i stated the suggested if and defind them to v1=b1 abd so on if correct

Comment: @YarinShani The "biggest" should be assigned from the "windows", not the other way around. So if the "window" variables are named `v1` etc., and the "biggest" are `b1` etc., then you need `b1 = v1` instead.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `n` is uninitialized, so it's undefined behavior when you do `while (n != 1){`. So technically, there's no guarantee that anything works past that. You should initialize it, for example by setting it to `0` (or any other value that's not `1`, in this case):

```
int n = 0;
```

But the issue that you observe is because you have another `int n;` in your loop, which shadows the outer `n` (the one that is checked in the `while` condition). So the `cin >> n;` only ever modifies that inner `n`. The outer one will stay at the same uninitialized value. So if that value made it enter the loop, it will never exit the loop, because `n != 1` is always `true`.

Remove the `int n;` inside the loop to solve the problem.

Comment: thank you for noticing ,  i changed it , but still cant understand how to use the Nth input

Comment: You'll have to make three variables for your three biggest values and then use `if/else` constructs to find out whether the new number is bigger than the smallest of the three and change them accordingly.

Comment: it seems that your comment solve for the biggest 3 numbers and what im asking for is to find the sum of the biggest 3 with dependence of the order they were submitted

Comment: To sum up the three biggest numbers, you need to find out what numbers those are. That's the difficult part. Summing them up is easy, that's just `a+b+c`. Also, how is a sum dependent on the order of the submitted numbers? Your question seems unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, what you need is 4 variables to account the actual list and its sums (3 for the list and 1 for the sum of it)

You need 3 more variables to account the actual list.

At each interaction, you have two things to do:

- Compare the sum of actual list with the stored one. If the sum the actual list is greater than that stored, actualize it
- For each new number, rotate you variables that account for the actual list.

In pseudo code:

```
v3 = v2;
v2 = v1;
v1 = new_number;
```

Comment: wow sounds brilliant but im having difficulty to get the inputs into the list

Comment: Initialize all variables with 0, for example, At each interaction (new input), just update your list as mentioned